# "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY" With Array of grouped items for History tracking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a reference table for a large dataset, where I need to match up data using the ID as the PK. However, I also need to manage the history of the alias changes associated with the ID, for analysis further down the line - Any help or suggestions are appreciated. I've left examples of the desired output below;

Currently I am using this;

```
SELECT ID, Email FROM (
  SELECT ID, Email, EventDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
  ORDER BY EventDate DESC) recent_record FROM 
    (
    SOURCE TABLE
    )  
 ) WHERE recent_record = 1
```

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEr0b.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id, 
  string_agg(email order by eventDate desc limit 1) as currentAlias,
  array_agg(struct(email, eventDate) order by eventDate) as aliasHistory
from  your_table
group by id
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the aliases (included the most recent one) in an ordered array with the [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) function:

```
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(Email ORDER BY EventDate DESC) as Aliases
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

In this case the first element of the array will be the current alias.

Using that as a nested query you can get the current email as a separate column

```
SELECT ID, Aliases[OFFSET(0)] as currentEmail, Aliases FROM (
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(Email ORDER BY EventDate DESC) as Aliases
FROM SampleTable GROUP BY ID)
```